# Multi sites: how to give each site a home single entry?

Tags: multi-site, singles

I've been experimenting with Craft 3 and Multi Sites and feel like I'm missing something...

My organisation has a main homepage and multiple sub-sites. I have a Single Section called 'home' that creates the main site homepage. I want each sub-site to have an individual homepage too. Each sub-site should only be able to edit their own homepage entry.

If I enable the 'home' Single Section across all sub-sites then they can all edit the main site homepage entry. The 'Propagate entries across all enabled sites?' option isn't available for Single Sections.

So how do I achieve this? :|

Answer (score 2):

It's well explained in your section settings in the CP: there is a table with the settings for each site with a hint to leave the field blank if it should be the homepage.

If you want to have a different entry as the homepage for another site create a new single section for that site.

#### Single Entry 1

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| site              | url            | template     |
-----------------------------------------------------
| english, disabled |                |              |
| german, enabled   |                | index.twig   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

#### Single Entry 2

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| site              | url            | template     |
------------------------------------------------------
| english, enabled  |                | index.twig    |
| german, disabled  |                |               |
------------------------------------------------------
```

That way users won't be able to edit the homepage entry from other sites.
Another approach would be to limit the site permissions for your editors so they'll only be able to edit the elements which are connected to their site.

Comment: Thanks for your response Robin. These settings are only available within the Section settings, not on a per entry basis. So are you suggesting setting up a Single Section ('homeEnglish', 'homeGerman'...) for each site? What I'm trying to achieve is a different Entry within the Single Section 'home' for each site.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean singles have only one entry. So It is not possible to define settings per entry. Or you can - as I said - create only one multi site entry and restrict your user permissions so your editors have only access to a certain site

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Because it is possible to restrict entries in a Channel Section to one Site I thought it would be possible to do the same for a Single Section (ie: every Site gets 1 Entry in a Single Section).

Comment: well.. it is. In your section settings

Comment: @jack4000 I would prefer it to be like you exptected it to be. But the docs have it very clear: "In the settings for each Channel Section is an option to propagate entries in that section across all sites. This is enabled by default, and is the only option for Single and Structure sections." https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/sites.html#propagating-entries-across-all-enabled-sites